# Linux mint 18.3, convert ext4 to btrfs

Tags: linux-mint, conversion, ext4, ubuntu-16.04, btrfs

I have upgraded to `Linux Mint 18.3`, but all are `EXT4`, but I understand now, that `BTRFS` is awesome is much better with snapshots then `EXT4`, but I followed this: [*How To Convert An ext3/ext4 Root File System To btrfs On Ubuntu 12.10*](https://www.howtoforge.com/how-to-convert-an-ext3-ext4-root-file-system-to-btrfs-on-ubuntu-12.10).

I think, it is outdated for sure.

But it doesn't work with. I get this error with `GRUB` `error: sparse file not allowed`, I can boot everywhere except I get this error, but with my root system it doesn't work.

For other menus like `Windows`, `Clonzilla`, and the rest work.

Do you know how to convert all `EXT4` to `BTRFS` today?

Comment: Well, I'd reconsider using BTRFS. Yes, it has many advantages, but you may also easily end up with filesystem error, which is unrepairable (coleague's personal experience on OpenSUSE...).

Comment: actually, I kept `EXT4`, it is not the best still... same here... ciao!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suppose you should start with the current [btrfs documentation](https://btrfs.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/Manpage/btrfs-convert). The good news is that conversion from ext4 is indeed supported, but tutorial you linked did indeed skip some steps listed in the linked wiki manpage. You should also be able to follow the instructions on the [Arch wiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Btrfs#Ext3.2F4_to_Btrfs_conversion) for this.

The error message should be benign, in the sense it should show the error but allow you to boot . See for example [here](https://forums.linuxmint.com/viewtopic.php?t=86954) (Mint, 2011) and [here](https://forum.manjaro.org/t/grub-btrfs-error-sparse-file-not-allowed/2016) (manjaro, 2016).