# Is it safe to convert EXT4 to BTRFS inplace?

Tags: linux, filesystems, ext4, btrfs

Ubuntu 20.04 makes it very hard to create an encrypted installation with BTRFS file system. Thus, I have an encrypted installation running on ext4. For a number of reasons I would like to use BTRFS file system.

I heard a lot of rumour that inplace conversions are dangerous and might lead to strange misbehaviour *in the long run*. Is it considered to flawlessly work nowadays or should I rather stick with ext4?

I am aware of [that other question](https://superuser.com/questions/1272767/linux-mint-18-3-convert-ext4-to-btrfs) but it treats more how to do it, not whether its safe. Also, its quite old already.

Answer (score 0):

No, its not safe.

I did the test. I took an old ThinkPad and installed a fresh Ubuntu 20.04 on it (without network configuration, thus without updates). During installation I checked the boxes to create an LVM that hosts an encrypted partition. Then

1. I ensured the installation succeeded
2. booted into the live system again
3. unencrypted the partition
4. converted the file system using `sudo btrfs-convert`
5. changed the file system type entry in `/etc/fstab` to `btrfs`
6. `sudo reboot`

Then the boot hangs right after unencrypting the partition. Unfortunately I do not get a usefull error message. It seems as if it tries to run `fsck` but I am not sure.

I repeated that two times. Both times the result was the same.

Comment: probably you need to update grub to make it boot properly

Comment: I doubt, because when the boot gets stuck the boot has passed grub sucessfully. Anyhow, my intent was only to see if it was possible with very few effort and thats not the case, at least for my threshold for "very few effort".

Comment: @MaxGörner Well, as I show in my answer, your answer is wrong. You simply forgot to take into account important details such as telling grub where to boot from. And no, that's not at odds with your proclaimed error symptoms, because your grub config still was told to boot from volumes with a different UUID, didn't know about subvolumes etc. So yes, it sped past the boot loader and therefore was technically already in Linux, but it failed to mount the _real_ `/` when trying the handover from initrd to real `/`. Repeating the same mistakes is no proof something doesn't work in principle.

Answer (score 0):

**Yes, it is safe.** It's a bit of an involved process, but I just walked through it with Ubuntu 20.04. The goal here was to keep my old `/` as subvolume `@oldroot` while being able to install a new system in parallel. I also wanted to move `/home` into its own `@home` subvolume.

To sum it up:

- status up front: `ext4` for `/` and `/boot` and a system that boots the installation (in my case it was also Ubuntu 20.04 as in the question!)
- status after conversion: `ext4` for `/boot` but now `btrfs` for `/` and *again* a booting installation (i.e. same system "migrated" to `btrfs`)

Why do I say it is safe?: because [`btrfs-convert`](https://btrfs.readthedocs.io/en/latest/Convert.html) provides an option to rollback. Everything that could make it fail (power outage, failing disks) is equally applicable without a conversion. **Please note**, however, that the man page for `btrfs-convert` does mention options you should *not* run on the converted volume *until* you are certain that you don't have to roll back! Notably `btrfs balance` should *not* be run.

#### Prerequisites

What you need are `btrfs-progs` and a handful of other tools *and* some knowledge. A live booted Linux.

##### Points to remember:

1. the volume UUID of the old `ext4` volume will differ from that of the new `btrfs` volume
2. each `btrfs` subvolume will have its own UUID, can be listed with `btrfs subvolume list -u /path`
3. `/etc/fstab` needs to be adjusted after conversion
4. for good measure you should again:

   - `update-initramfs -ck all`
   - `grub-install`
   - `update-grub`

#### The process

*Most* of the commands below need to be run as superuser (`root`).

1. (optional) the assumption is that you want to convert the `ext4` root drive of a working Linux installation into `btrfs` and migrate `/home` into its own subvolume in the process

   - it's probably a good idea to briefly enable `root` on your system and give a password, because the `root` user won't have to rely on an extra mount point `/home` such as other users would ... this could be disabled after successful conversion
2. boot into a live system such that the partitions that are involved won't be mounted ("in use")

   - NB: I used a Manjaro ISO, so it doesn't even depend on Ubuntu
   - I strongly suggest to store the output of `blkid` and `lsblk -f` in a text file and keeping it handy (alternatively print it ... `|lpr`) for later reference

     - You are mostly interested in `/` and `/boot` for the scope of this procedure
3. inside the live system use `blkid` or `lsblk -f` to identify the partition you want to convert from `ext4` to `btrfs`, let's say `/dev/sda2` is your `@oldroot`-to-be
4. kick off the conversion: `btrfs-convert -p -L /dev/sda2` (adjust as needed, `-L` allegedly copies the label but didn't work for me and `-p` shows progress)
5. (optional) once the conversion is finished I ran a `partprobe` for good measure
6. (optional) repeat the `blkid` or `lsblk -f` step from step 1 to note the new status down
7. create a `/target` directory
8. `mount -t btrfs /dev/sda2 /target`
9. now inquire about the existing subvolumes on the converted partition with `btrfs subvolume list -u /`. It should show something along the lines of:

   ```
   ID 256 gen 3 top level 5 uuid -    path ext2_saved
   ```

   **NB:** this, dear reader, is your ticket to rolling back to `ext4` (I didn't have to do it, so I am not going into that at all here)
10. the old contents of `/` are now mounted at `/target` but we want those in subvolumes, so we need to create them:

    1. old contents of `/`: `btrfs subvolume create /target/@oldroot`
    2. old contents of `/home`: `btrfs subvolume create /target/@home`
11. now it's time to move your old data into the subvolumes:

    1. `mv /target/home/* /target/@home/` should take care of moving the *contents* of the original `/home` folder
    2. then `cd /target` and `mv` everything else which isn't `@home` or `@oldroot` into `/target/@oldroot/`
12. at this point `/target` should only contain the subvolumes at the top level, this is what we were going for
13. time to `chroot` into our "old system" in the subvolume `@oldroot`

    1. `cd; umount /target` because we don't want to mount the root of the `btrfs` now
    2. `mount -t btrfs -o subvol=@oldroot /target` to mount the old root file system
    3. `mount /dev/sda1 /target/boot` ... you *did* note down what your old `/boot` was, right? Plug it in here instead of `/dev/sda1`
    4. bind-mount some of the stuff from your live boot system into `/target`: `for i in sys proc dev dev/pts run sys/firmware/efi/efivars; do mount -o bind "/$i" "/target/$i"; done` ... if you are on a BIOS and not an EFI system the last item will inevitably fail, this should not be a problem
    5. time to "enter" our original system: `chroot /target /bin/bash` (of course if you know another shell was installed, feel free to use that instead)

       - once inside your `chroot` you should be `root` (as on the outside`, but if you ran it via` sudo`chances are you need to`export HOME=/root` to rectify a wrongly set home directory
       - on the same note, you may need to `export PATH=$PATH:/sbin:/usr/sbin` to make those binaries available to you
    6. now that you are inside the old system, edit its `/etc/fstab`, what I like to do is to append the output of something like `blkid|grep btrfs` to it and then edit it

       - plug the correct UUID into the entry for `/`, e.g. like so:

         ```
         UUID=946838ea-c227-40a2-aa2c-ae17dd4dfece / btrfs subvol=@oldroot 0 1
         ```
       - and don't forget that `/home` now is also a mount point:

         ```
         UUID=946838ea-c227-40a2-aa2c-ae17dd4dfece /home btrfs subvol=@home 0 1
         ```

         **NB:** note how the UUID is the same, because we're mounting *subvolumes* off of the same volume
       - perhaps verify the other mount points and *for now* disable those that you don't absolutely need; however `/boot` is of particular importance and should *still* be valid even without editing
       - exit the editor from `/etc/fstab`
       - Run in order (if you did the proper steps to set up the `chroot` they should all work without any issue):

         - `update-initramfs -ck all`
         - `grub-install`
         - `update-grub`
       - Verify that the root partition is mentioned in `/boot/grub/grub.cfg`, e.g. with:

         ```
         grep -P --color '(946838ea-c227-40a2-aa2c-ae17dd4dfece|subvol=@\w+)' /boot/grub/grub.cfg
         ```
14. exit the `chroot` (of course you're free to dabble around in it before a reboot)
15. reboot the live system
16. you should now have successfully booted into your "new" old system, just from `btrfs` this time (if not, see Troubleshooting below)

##### Troubleshooting

Obviously there are many things that could potentially go wrong, some of which apply to *any* use of a computer even without converting from `ext4` to `btrfs`. Can't cover all of those here. However, I'll mention one issue I ran into and give a hint how to resolve issues you could run into:

- When I tried to boot I was dropped on the TTY to log in and did so as `root`. I had briefly seen plenty of errors before the login prompt showed up.

  - When I logged in (as `root`) it turned out `/` was mounted read-only
  - Trying to `mount -o remount,rw /` failed, complaining about `errors=remount-ro` being an unknown option ... oh well
  - this option was still set -- because I carried it over from `ext4` times -- for `/`
  - so I created a temporary directory in one of the few writable locations, mounted the `@oldroot` subvolume there and edited `/etc/fstab` this way
  - in fact the system proceeded to boot after I then issued another `mount -o remount,rw /`, but I rebooted afresh anyway
- If something goes wrong, don't panic!

  - Check that you followed the instructions to the letter (with the allowed deviations considered)
  - Make sure you understand what your problem is, based on the errors you receive, i.e. *read the error messages* and process them
  - If you think it's a lost cause, use `btrfs-convert` to roll back to the old `ext4`, but this also requires undoing the other changes such as in `/etc/fstab` and regenerating initrd and installing/updating grub configs.

PS: this answer was written on a system that yesterday ran from an `ext4` and now runs the same exact installation from `btrfs`.